# how can i manage some design patterns to solve this problem

Tags: design-patterns

In a given distributed system, subsystems interact in complex and uncontrolled fashion. The goal is to design the system so that access to some of the services of each subsystem can be restricted dynamically (for a certain subset of clients).These restrictions should be continuously reconsidered and reapplied at runtime ,based on the status of the system (as to workload distribution) and the history of problematic accesses (e.g erroneous service requests) .
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What proposed solutions do you have ?

Comment: I don't have any proposed solution but i guess, I should use Broker because it is distributed (or micro kernel or pipes and filters) , maybe Mediator because subsystems interact in complex way , may be Protection Proxy to restrict access to services , maybe Facade for subsystems , and also State or Strategy (I don't know which one) .All in all i am not sure of these. I guess sth is missing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are plenty of solutions. they all basically use the principle of adding a level of indirection to access your data, so that you can make your considerations runtime, and apply them accordingly.

in practice you need to make a decision on how you want to retrieve the right information you need:
you can use a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and add an interface so that you can model different behaviors according to what you need.

you can go for another behavioral pattern, like [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) if your data tend to be coupled, and you instead would like to have them as separate as possible (you mention that they are systems, so maybe you don't want to have them at the same level)

you can make it simple and query an object/function/table to retrieve that information for you, and apply it to your object(s)

The specific solution might vary, depending on your case, but in general, what you need is "an extra piece of code" where you can make clearly your considerations and apply them.

[Behavioral patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) are especially good for this.